# ASP.NET MVC: set value in other field on my view, how to?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where the user can change some settings, its basically a "edit" page. When the user checks a particular value in a radio group i set a hidden field (its a invisible input type=text field), but when i load the page i want that hidden field set from my code. How to do this? JQuery? or can i "findControl" somehow?

This is the "hidden" field:

```
<div style="display: none">
<input type="text" name="HiddenImageId" id="HiddenImageId" value="" />
</div>
```

The above hidden field is set from a jquery that executes when a radio-button is clicked. But when I load in "edit" mode I want myself to set the "hidden" field.

Further down my view i load all the radio-buttons:

```
<% if (file.Id == imageFile.Id)
   { %>
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="filename" class="filename" id="<%= file.Id.ToString()%>" />
<% }
   else
   { %>
        <input type="radio" name="filename" class="filename" id="<%= file.Id.ToString()%>" />
 <%} %>
```

When I set the checked attribute I want to set the value of my hidden fiddle to the files ID.

Comment: Why aren't you setting the type to hidden instead? Like this: <input type="hidden" name="HiddenImageId" id="HiddenImageId" value="" /> You don't need the <div style="display: none">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably benefit a lot from making better use of the [Html Helpers] in ASP.NET MVC.

You could, for example, output your "hidden" text input like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("HiddenImageId", imageFile.Id) %>
```

If `imageFile` can be null, you might want to add a check for that - use shorthand if to make it look nice:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("HiddenImageId", imageFile != null ? imageFile.Id : "") %>
```

You could also probably improve your code for the radiobuttons significantly by using [Html.RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470335.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

just like you are doing

```
id="<%= file.Id.ToString()%>"
```

you can do

```
<input type="text" name="HiddenImageId" id="HiddenImageId" value="<%= file.Id.ToString()%>" />
```

or whatever the code is to get your value

Comment: This is actually more of what I was trying to do, and I ended up with a solution similar to this (If a field in my hidden area has a value, then I show that hidden area). Quick and dirty. Just the way I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the HtmlHelper extensions in both cases.

```
<div style="display: none">
   <%= Html.TextBox( "HiddenImageId",
                     file.Id == imageFile.Id ? file.Id.ToString() : "" ) %>
</div>

<%= Html.RadioButton( "filename",
                      "",
                      file.Id == imageFile.Id,
                      new { @class = "filename", id = file.Id.ToString() } ) %>
```

or if you wanted to use a hidden input instead, skip the invisible DIV, and use

```
<%= Html.Hidden( "HiddenImageId", 
                 file.Id == imageFile.Id ? file.Id.ToString() : "" ) %>
```